# Modifying data contract of value field

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have to use a .NET builtin class for JSON deserialization, and found `System.Web.Script.Serialization`:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Deserialize<T>(str)
```

It is not possible to switch to `Newtonsoft.Json` because this would be an unwanted dependency. I have the following C# class as a deserialization target:

```
public class PrintJob {
    public bool PrintWeekends = true;
    public int NumberOfCopies = 2;
}
```

But as per the data contract, the sender *may* also send a `null` value to indicate that the falsy value be used:

```
{PrintWeekends: null, NumberOfCopies: null}
```

is equivalent to

```
{PrintWeekends: false, NumberOfCopies: 0}
```

This weird data contract cannot be easily changed. The chosen deserializer, of course, doesn't ignore the `null` by default, and throws an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   NULL kann nicht in einen Werttyp konvertiert werden.
>
> bei System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
>   bei System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.AssignToPropertyOrField(Object propertyValue, Object o, String memberName, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError)
>   ...

Can I modify the deserializer to fulfil the required data contract, and if so, how?

Comment: Can't you make the variables nullable, I think that will solve your problem without changing serializer

Comment: Is that a problem for just this type (`PrintJob`) or you have the same problem for many other types?

Comment: @Evk I hope that I will have the same problem for other types in the future, otherwise the data contract would be inconsistent - and that's the only thing worse than a weird data contract.

Comment: I think you are out of luck then with `JavascriptSerializer` (except maybe you can play with custom JavascriptConverter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the contract variables as nullable type which will allow null values also from user and then you can treat them as default values

```
public class PrintJob {
    public bool? PrintWeekends = true;
    public int? NumberOfCopies = 2;
}
```